# Gestionar ofertas de suscripciones con la Biblioteca de Facturación Google Play desde Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play-services, pago-in-app

Llevo tiempo manejando suscripciones de Google Play desde la app de Android en la que trabajo, usando la **versión 4.0 de la Biblioteca de Facturación Google Play** (por el momento no es factible actualizar a la 5.0). Ahora se me plantea la necesidad de ofrecer períodos de prueba gratuitos en las suscripciones, por lo que he creado una oferta en la consola de Google Play por cada una de las suscripciones donde quiero ofrecer la prueba gratuita, con la siguiente configuración:

- Criterio de participación: **determinado por el desarrollador** (no quiero que Google decida a qué usuarios le muestra la oferta, quiero ser yo quien lo decida desde mi código y con mis propios criterios)
- Una fase de tipo "Prueba gratuita" de 1 mes de duración (que es la misma periodicidad de cada suscripción)

Mi problema es que no soy capaz de acceder a las ofertas desde el código. No las veo por ninguna parte ni tampoco he encontrado en la [documentación oficial de la Biblioteca de Facturación Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) un ejemplo claro de cómo gestionar esto.

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo que siempre he hecho para obtener mis suscripciones, mostrarlas en la app y lanzar el flujo de compra. Por ejemplo, si quiero obtener una única suscripción cuyo id de plan es `"android_mensual`", de nombre "Suscripción Mensual" y con un precio base de 49 €, hago lo siguiente después de iniciar el `BillingClient`:

```
mBillingClient?.let { billingClient ->
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().apply {
                    setSkusList(listOf("android_mensual"))
                    setType(SkuType.SUBS)
                }
    
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        if (!skuDetailsList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    
                            // A not empty products details list has been successfully retrieved.
                            ...
                        } else {
    
                            // Products details list is null or empty.
                            ...
                        }
                    } else {
    
                        // The response code is not OK.
                        ...
                    }
                }
            } ?: run {
    
                // The BillingClient was null.
                ...
            }
```

Si todo va bien, obtengo en `skuDetailsList` una lista con los detalles de todos los productos requeridos. En este ejemplo la lista devuelta contiene un solo elemento `skuDetailsList[0]` de este tipo:

```
SkuDetails: {"productId":"android_mensual","type":"subs","title":"Suscripción Mensual","name":"Suscripción Mensual","iconUrl":" ... ","description":"Suscripción Mensual","price":"49,00 €","price_amount_micros":49000000,"price_currency_code":"EUR","skuDetailsToken":" ... ","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M"}
```

El título y el precio que saco de estos elementos de la lista son los que muestro en mi app, para que el usuario elija qué suscripción desea adquirir. Mi idea, con los períodos de prueba gratuitos, sería obtener esa misma información con un precio de 0 € para poder mostrar esa oferta del mismo modo dentro de mi app. Y aquí es donde empiezan mis problemas.

¿Dónde estarían los datos de la oferta? Tan sólo recibo los parámetros de la suscripción original, pero no veo la oferta asociada por ninguna parte. De hecho, si capturo el resultado de `skuDetailsList[0].freeTrialPeriod` obtengo una cadena vacía, lo cual es bastante extraño porque, [según dice aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getFreeTrialPeriod()), eso parece indicar que la suscripción no tiene un período de prueba configurado, cuando de hecho lo configuré y activé hace varios días en la consola de Google Play, para cada una de mis suscripciones.

Pero aun si llegara a obtener un valor no vacío en `skuDetailsList[0].freeTrialPeriod`, tampoco tengo nada claro cómo podría recibir y mostrar esa oferta de prueba gratuita en mi app. ¿Llegarían también dentro de `skuDetailsList`, como intuyo? ¿Tal vez debería usar unos parámetros diferentes en la llamada a `querySkuDetailsAsync`? ¿O habría que hacer una llamada diferente?

Cualquier idea que me ayude a salir de este atolladero será bienvenida. Muchas gracias de antemano.

**Edito y añado:**

Las ofertas están creadas desde hace varios días, como se puede ver en las capturas que adjunto, así que entiendo que ahí no está el problema de no recibir el campo `freeTrialPeriod`, salvo que estos cambios estén tardando mucho en propagarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es: aunque llegue a recibir un valor tipo "P1M" en el campo `freeTrialPeriod`, ¿cómo parametrizo luego la llamada a `launchBillingFlow` para efectuar la compra, de modo que pueda indicarle a Google que esa compra es un free trial y no una compra de suscripción al precio normal? A esa llamada le tengo que pasar los datos `SkuDetails` del plan. ¿Si le paso el `freeTrialPeriod` relleno, ya con eso bastaría para que Google supiera que se trata de una compra con importe 0?

**Edito de nuevo**

Planteo mejor un par de escenarios para explicar mejor mi duda, **sin perder de vista que el criterio de participación en la oferta es "determinado por el desarrollador", es decir, no quiero que Google decida por mí si la oferta se aplica a un comprador o no, eso lo quiero decidir yo desde mi app para cada cliente que compre**:

**Escenario 1:**

1. Tengo un **cliente A** que nunca ha comprado suscripciones en mi app, y **quiero que disfrute del free trial al comprar por primera vez**.
2. La llamada a querySkuDetailsAsync me devuelve un plan con estos `SkuDetails`: `{"productId":"android_mensual", ... ,"price":"49,00 €", ... ,"freeTrialPeriod":"P1M"}` (o eso espero, llegar a recibir un valor no vacío en `freeTrialPeriod`)
3. Cuando el cliente A compre la suscripción, uso los `SkuDetails` obtenidos en el paso anterior para parametrizar la llamada a `launchBillingFlow` y lanzar el proceso de compra.
4. **Asumo que Google le va a aplicar el free trial por un mes**, y que vencido ese tiempo, si auto-renueva la suscripción se le pasará a cobrar automáticamente cada mes el precio sin oferta, 49 €.

**Escenario 2:**

1. Tengo otro **cliente B** que tampoco ha comprado nunca suscripciones en mi app, pero por el motivo que sea **no quiero que disfrute del free trial al comprar por primera vez**.
2. La llamada a `querySkuDetailsAsync` me devuelve los mismos `SkuDetails` de antes.
3. Cuando el cliente B compre la suscripción, ¿uso también esos mismos `SkuDetails` para parametrizar la llamada a `launchBillingFlow` y lanzar el proceso de compra? **¿Cómo le indico a Google que a este cliente B no le aplique el free trial y que le tiene que empezar a cobrar ya los 49 € desde esta primera compra?**

Answer (score 0):

Mencionas que usas la biblioteca de facturación 4.0:

> implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'

Primeramente, si tienes duda sobre los parámetros necesarios para `querySkuDetailsAsync()`, debe ser una lista del o los SKUs (Ids de Productos) que tiene relacionada tu aplicación:

```
            ArrayList<String> listSkus = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] arrSkus = strProductIds.split(",");
            Collections.addAll(listSkus, arrSkus);
            //listSkus:[m_suscription_2.0, y_suscription_2.0]
            ...
            ...
            SkuDetailsParams skuDetailsParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(listSkus).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).build();
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                ...
                ...
```

Al realizar la consulta de la información de cada producto usando la API se obtiene un json de esta forma:

```
{
    "productId": "y_suscription_2.0",
    "type": "subs",
    "title": "JORGESYS APP anual (JORGESYS APP)",
    "name": "JORGESYS APP Digital anual",
    "iconUrl": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/cuLDW12345P2nnepKjCEm8D7y0Bz00t2zEg-f2RvZeD_DnQCogX8yY01q5DSBCfcgg",
    "description": "Suscripción anual.",
    "price": "MX$2,599.00",
    "price_amount_micros": 1099000000,
    "price_currency_code": "MXN",
    "skuDetailsToken": "AEuh12345SRGqyActkh3TxJLqP8FTydq12345jdqWB24ThTaswHzbpv71y-l_hlQXzoMd-OmQ=",
    "subscriptionPeriod": "P1Y",
    "freeTrialPeriod": "P1W"
}
```

Como puedes ver, en este ejemplo, el producto tiene definido `"freeTrialPeriod": "P1W"`, que indica un periodo de prueba de 1 semana. En la información que tu obtienes no se indica el periodo de prueba (debe venir después de `subscriptionPeriod`):

```
{"productId":"android_mensual","...... ","subscriptionPeriod":"P1M"}
```

> eso parece indicar que la suscripción no tiene un período de prueba
> configurado

**De acuerdo a la información en tu pregunta me parece que el problema es precisamente lo que investigaste, tu suscripción no tiene un periodo de prueba configurado, o estás consultando un `Product ID` que no tiene periodo de prueba.**

Asegura configurar correctamente el periodo de prueba que actualmente se agrega como "oferta", revisa:

[**Crea ofertas para aplicaciones pagadas**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7271135?hl=es-419)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> ¿cómo indicar en la llamada a `launchBillingFlow` para ejecutar la
> compra si se trata de un free trial o de la suscripción con el precio
> original?

Debes revisar que en la lista de productos usada en `SkuDetailsParams` contiene el `Product Id` : "prueba-con-free-trial". La administración del "free trial" lo realiza el sistema operativo con base en la configuración de la suscripción, no tienes que realizar alguna llamada para indicar que la compra tiene o no "free trial" o si el usuario ya hizo uso de esta prueba gratis, Google se encarga de eso.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @Jorgesys. Edito mi consulta original respondiendo a tu comentario. En resumen, las ofertas están dadas de alta desde la semana pasada, como puedes comprobar en las capturas adjuntas. Mi duda principal es que, una vez que consiga recibir un contenido no vacío en freeTrialPeriod, y dado que he establecido que el criterio de participación en la oferta será "determinado por el desarrollador", ¿cómo indicar en la llamada a launchBillingFlow para ejecutar la compra si se trata de un free trial o de la suscripción con el precio original?

Comment: Debes revisar que en la lista de productos usada en SkuDetailsParams contiene "prueba-con-free-trial", la administración del "free trial" lo realiza el sistema operativo con base en la configuración de la suscripción. revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo, @Jorgesys, pero recuerda que el criterio de participación en la oferta es "determinado por el desarrollador", y ese criterio no es necesariamente que el usuario ya haya disfrutado del free trial. Entonces sigo sin tener claro cómo parametrizar la llamada a launchBillingFlow dependiendo de si en la compra decido que se aplique la oferta o no. ¿Elimino el objeto "freeTrialPeriod" en los SkuDetails del parámetro de launchBillingFlow si no quiero que un usuario que nunca ha comprado la suscripción disfrute del free trial?

Comment: He vuelto a editar mi consulta original, @Jorgesys, para añadir al final un par de escenarios donde explico mejor, creo, mis dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mí mismo porque ya he dado con la solución por mi cuenta, por si le pudiera servir a alguien más que esté en la misma situación.

Para que los free trials funcionen con la **versión 4.0 de la Biblioteca de Facturación de Google Play** hay que crear ofertas para cada suscripción del modo siguiente:

- Dentro del panel de control de Google Play, Monetización → Suscripciones, elegir la suscripción que se desea editar.
- Una vez dentro de la pantalla con los detalles de la suscripción, clic en “Añadir oferta”.
- Rellenar los siguientes datos de la oferta:

  - ID de oferta: por ejemplo, “free-trial”.
  - Criterios de participación: "Adquisición de clientes nuevos" con el tipo de autorización "Nunca han tenido ninguna suscripción". *Lo ideal para mí habría sido seleccionar aquí el criterio de participación "Determinado por el desarrollador", pero dicho criterio provocaría que la oferta no fuese retrocompatible y que no se pudiera usar con métodos de facturación obsoletos, por lo cual no sería accesible desde el código de la app usando la versión 4.0 de la Biblioteca de Facturación de Google Play. **Éste era el gran problema**.*
  - Añadir una fase de tipo "Prueba gratuita".
- Aplicar → Guardar → Activar la oferta.
- ***MUY IMPORTANTE***: de vuelta a la pantalla anterior con los detalles de la suscripción, abrir el menú de la oferta desde el icono de los tres puntos verticales y seleccionar "Usar con métodos de facturación obsoletos". De este modo la oferta es retrocompatible y es devuelta por el método obsoleto `querySkuDetailsAsync()` de la versión 4.0 de la Biblioteca de Facturación de Google Play, por lo que se podrá gestionar desde el código de la app.

**Hecho esto, las llamadas a `querySkuDetailsAsync()` desde el código de la app devolverán ya el campo `freeTrialPeriod` cuando la oferta esté disponible. Y en la posterior llamada a `launchBillingFlow`, el flujo de compras de Google Play le ofrecerá al usuario el free trial directamente, sin que haya que hacer nada más dentro del código de la app.**